# Variants of Correlation Between Continuous Variables X,Y where one of X,Y is not Stochastic

Tags: correlation

EDIT: I was reading : [Why is correlation not very useful when one of the variables is categorical?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256344/why-is-correlation-not-very-useful-when-one-of-the-variables-is-categorical/256351?noredirect=1#comment811200_256351)

When I thought of the issue of correlation between two continuous variables X,Y , when one of them is not stochastic ( obviously at least one of the two must be stochastic), as in ,e .g., hours studied/week vs GPA or hours of exercise vs blood pressure. Here standard correlation does not seem to say much: If X is not stochastic, it does not in any way depend on Y. Is any other concept used in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here standard correlation does not seem to say much: If X is not stochastic, it does not in any way depend on Y.

Y can still depend on X, though. In that case correlation can still make sense but typically people will look to regression-like methods for describing the relationship (which encompasses correlation). However, be aware of [omitted variable bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted_variable_bias)

> since X does not depend on Y, we end up with Corr(X,Y) $\neq$ Corr(Y,X)?

Correlation is a symmetric measure - if you interchange x and y the correlation is unchanged.

```
 x=1:10               # fixed x
 y=3+0.1*x+rnorm(10)  # y depends on x
 cor(x,y)
[1] 0.6765819
 cor(y,x)
[1] 0.6765819
```

Comment: But then hours of study are related to GPA? Or change in GPA affects hours of study?

Comment: I mean, I understand the Mathematics behind it but these don't seem to reflect the fact that a change in GPA does not lead to a change in hours of study.

Comment: You seem to be confusing association with causation. Correlation is not causation. If GPA is related to amount of study, amount of study is related to GPA.

Comment: No, clearly there is no causation, but I am having trouble even seeing an association between the two.

Comment: If more study implies higher GPA, then the higher GPAs will have a higher proportion of students who study more

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks, Glen_b

Comment: @MSIS - Instead of reasoning on causation I would suggest reasoning on prediction. If correlation is high, we can predict that somebody with higher GPA has studied more hours and we will tend to be right.

Comment: Ok, I see it as a sort of contrapositive.