# How to compute the correlation between a qualitative and a quantitative variable?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data

My study is about the correlation of the person's gender and his or her score in a questionnaire about gender stereotyping. The higher the score in the questionnaire means he or she gender stereotypes more. What kind of correlation statistic should I use? Can I find it in Excel?

Comment: There are a number of other threads that also cover this information, eg, see: [Correlation between a nominal (IV) and a continuous (DV) variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/119835/).

Comment: I think you will find the information you need in the linked threads. Please 
read them. If it isn't what you want / you still have a question afterwards, 
come back here & edit your question to state what you learned & what you still 
need to know. Then we can provide the information you need without just 
duplicating material elsewhere that already didn't help you.