# Correlation metric for 0-1 vector and real values vector

Tags: correlation, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, spearman-rho, metric

I am looking for a right correlation metric to measure correlation between two vectors. The dimensionality of the vectors is around 100. The first vector has real values as the elements and the second vector has 0,1 values.

Spearman rho is widely used as a correlation metric between two real-valued vectors, but my case is slightly different (0,1 values in one of the vectors). Whether Mann–Whitney U test is more appropriate in my case than Spearman Rho?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: If you are not limited Mann-Whitney and Spearman Rho, I would suggest you to consider boxplot / linear models as suggested by [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable)

Answer (score 1):

First, Mann Whitney U is not a nonparametric alternative to correlation, it is an alternative to t-tests. It tests for differences between the two groups, not relationship.

Second, to your question, it looks like [point-biserial correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-biserial_correlation_coefficient) is what you want. As per Wikipedia:

> The point biserial correlation coefficient (rpb) is a correlation
>   coefficient used when one variable (e.g. Y) is dichotomous; Y can
>   either be "naturally" dichotomous, like whether a coin lands heads or
>   tails, or an artificially dichotomized variable. In most situations it
>   is not advisable to dichotomize variables artificiall