# How level of measurement help us in selecting correct type of correlation

Tags: correlation

How level of measurement help us in selecting correct type of
correlation

Comment: Welcome to CV! What do you mean by level of measurement? Your question is not clear, you can edit it with the button below to add some detail.

Comment: I think the question is related to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable/

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that, by "level of measurement" you mean the "nominal, ordinal, interval, ratio" system introduced by Stevens and abused ever since.

First, I think you should be aware that these levels aren't exhaustive - that is, there are measurements that don't fit, see [my blog post on this](https://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/nominal-ordinal-interval-ratio-stevens-typology-and-some-problems-with-it/).

Notwithstanding the above, we can say some things:

1. Nominal with anything - Unless the nominal variable takes only 2 levels, correlation doesn't really make sense. There are measures of association, but not correlation.
2. Ordinal with ordinal, interval or ratio - It will often be best to use Spearman's rank correlation.
3. Interval or ratio with interval or ratio - Here, Pearson's correlation is a good place to start, but you need to be aware of other possible problems (look up Anscombe's quartet for some problems that can occur).

Comment: (+1) Kendall's various measures of rank correlation deserve mention too.