# How to find the values of array indices which most strongly correlate with a variable?

Tags: correlation, matrix

Say I have a list of arrays like this:

```
A: [0, 3, 5, 3],
B: [1, 3, 2, 5],
...
```

I want to find the values in `B` (1, 2, or 3) that most strongly correlates with the value 0 in `A` (whose value is a boolean).

I know I can use a correlation matrix to find correlations between pairs of indices, but I want to find correlations between one index and 3 others simultaneously.

I'm looking for a search term really, not an R script because I intend to solve this in Node, but I doubt anyone here uses Node that this stuff.

**Update!**

I tried what @mzunhammer suggested, but my `B` is (1, 2, 3, ... 256) using his method (due to having 4 "slots" each with 4 possible values, zero to one).  And my sample is only 3,000, which gives me an average of only 12 samples for each possible value of `B`.  So I can't really decide on any winner with any real confidence.

Is there some sort of statistical magic I can do to get around this problem?

Comment: Please check my revision for clarity: The use of the term "index" may be misleading here and unnecessary. Why not filter B for A==0, then count occurrences of 1,2, and 3, then select the category with maximum count?

Comment: Thanks for the edit!  I will try what you propose, seems simple enough.

Comment: I think you may find this post helpful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119835/correlation-between-a-nominal-iv-and-a-continuous-dv-variable