# Reference level for multiple categorical variables

Tags: regression, categorical-data, least-squares

For an ***OLS model*** with one categorical variable as predictor, we often make dummies. One of the dummies - if the no. of categories is more than 2 is allowed to be subsumed by the intercept of the model. Such variable is taken for a reference level. It has been thoroughly explained, how to interpret such a reference level in [a part of this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/124618/332360). But, let's say that we have ***multiple categorical variables each having more than 2 categories.*** We make dummies out of all and use ***a dummy from each variable as a reference.*** How in this case must the parameters and intercept of the model be interpreted? Put differently (rather bluntly), what does the reference refer now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How in this case must the parameters and intercept of the model be interpreted?

It's just a generalization of the situation with a single multi-category predictor.

The intercept is the estimate when *all* such predictors are at their reference levels. The regression coefficients for other levels of those predictors are just the associated *differences* from what is estimated at the corresponding reference level.